# What is the best way to handle passing ISO date in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, isodate

I have the following html code and it works as intended when I hard code my dateTime.  However I am trying to pass a selected value from datePicker into my ct variable. The host application will only process ISOdates so am trying to convert on the client side.  Where am I going wrong?  thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function send()
{
var setParam1 = document.getElementById("fparam1").value;
var setParam2 = document.getElementById("fparam2").value;
var setDate = document.getElementById("dateid").value;
var ct=new Date(setDate).toISOString(); 
var ItemJSON;
    ItemJSON = '{"c8y_rlim":{"ul":{"value":'+setParam1+',"unit":"na"}},"time":'+ct+',"source": {"id":"681700"},"type":"c8y_ph"}';
    URL = "/measurement/measurements/" ;  //Your URL
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa('user:pw')); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.send(ItemJSON);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
function callbackFunction(xmlhttp) 
{
    //alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
}
</script>
<html>
<p><label for="DateID">DateTime:</label><br>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="Date" id="dateid"><br>
        <label for="fparam1">Param 1:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="fparam1" name="fparam1"><br>
        <label for="fparam2">Param 2:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="fparam2" name="fparam2"><br>
        </p><br><button type="submit" onclick="javascript:send()">Submit</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to send ISO datetimes or ISO dates? It looks like you're properly converting your `setDate` variable to an ISO datetime already.

Comment: iso datetimes.  As an example, "2020-07-01T13:15:43.416Z"

Comment: Also  I should have clarified that I receive a "Failed to parse JSON string" when attempting the above. Could be server side issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're properly setting the `ct` variable to an `ISOString`.

I believe your problem is with the manual JSON stringification you're doing.

In short, here's a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1p9jxo5/) that should do what you want.

To expand, javascript has built in [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) functionality for converting javascript object to json and vice-versa. So instead of manually concatenating your variables into a json string, you should create an object and then [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it!

```js
var setDate = document.getElementById("dateid").value;
var ct = new Date(setDate).toISOString();
var ItemObject = {
  c8y_rlim: {
    ul: {
      value: setParam1,
      unit: "na",
    },
  },
  time: ct,
  source: {
    id: 681700,
  },
  type: "c8y_ph",
};
var ItemJSON = JSON.stringify(ItemObject);
// ItemJSON is now a JSON string!
```

Some notes on this:

- It would be wise to wrap your JSON stringification code in a `try`/`catch` block, as it will throw an error if it can't properly serialize your object.
- Per W3C: *type="datetime-local" is not supported in Firefox, Safari or Internet Explorer 12 (or earlier).*
- At number 1 on [OWASP's top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) web app security risks is *injection*. Be wary of accepting raw input data without any sort of validation, especially when you're sending it off somewhere.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against writing your own JSON string directly, as it greatly increases the chance of a syntax error.

In this case, you are doing:

```
 /.../ "time":'+ct+' /.../
```

Which is the likely culprit behind breaking the JSON parsing on the server. The ISO datetime string is a **string**, and should thus be encoded as such, like this:

```
/.../ "time":"'+ct+'" /.../
```

But, an even better solution would be to build an object and then *stringify* this, just like [Sam explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62683663/150926).

```
var ItemJSON = JSON.stringify({
    ...
    'time': ct,
    ...
});
```

If you are working with a library or a framework, chances are it already supports passing JS objects directly, and it will handle converting to JSON itself.